# How to split a big Controller into different files in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

The Codeigniter Controller I am writing is getting big. How do I split the code into different files?

Answer (score 7):

Things you definitely should be doing:

- Anything that is strictly related to the controller, leave it alone.
- Make sure you move at least 99% of the view logic (html) into proper view files.
- Move all data processing into a [Model](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html). This includes database interaction, file manipulation, and form processing.

Things you probably should be doing:

- Anything that you are repeating frequently, create a function for it instead if possible.
- Gather all *related* functions and create [Libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) in `application/libraries/`.
- Whatever is left over, like independent common functions, create a [helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) file in `application/helpers`. If you know you will always need them, perhaps call it `global_helper.php` or something similar. You can break these out into different files later if this gets too crowded.
- Use a [base controller](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html). Create the file `core/MY_Controller.php`. Use this for anything you know you will need available globally to your controllers. You can create as many extensions you like in this file for different controller "types" (like Front_Controller, Back_Controller, Login_Controller), just make sure to extend the class in your controller files like `Blog_Controller extends MY_Controller`.

Make sure you have read the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html) thoroughly so you can take advantage of what the framework has built-in, you may be writing unnecessary code because you are unaware of the available features.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have too much functionality relating to different things in your controller. Try to figure out what you can split into separate controllers. Otherwise your controller might turn into [a god object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).